# Removing div elements dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to remove each div element I've created before dynamically when I click on it. Actually I created 10 div squares that contains random numbers between 0 and n(from input) and what I want is when I click on any of them to color it red during 3 seconds and then remove it and add the content to textarea.
Here is my code. I hope you can make me understand why it doesn't work... Thank you!

```js
var ti;
function Start()
{
 
 var n=document.getElementById("addnumber").value;
 for(i=1; i<=10; i++)
 {
  var divNew = document.createElement("div");
  divNew.style.height = "50px";
  divNew.style.width = "50px";
  divNew.style.border = "5px solid green"
  divNew.style.display = "inline-block";
  divNew.innerHTML= Math.floor((Math.random()*n)+1);
  document.body.appendChild(divNew);
 }
}


var listDivs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var l = document.getElementsByTagName("div").length;
for(let i=0; i<l; i++)
{
 listDivs[i].onclick = function(){ 
  ti = setInterval(del, 3000);
  function del(){
   listDivs[i].style.backgroundColor="red";
   if ( l == 0) 
    clearInterval(ti);
   else {
    document.body.removeChild(listDivs[i]);
    document.getElementsById("txt").value += listDivs[i].innerHTML;
   }
  }
 };
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 
 <title></title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="testjs.js"></script>
 <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>
 <p id="date"></p>
 <input type="number" name="Number:" id="addnumber">
 <button type="button" id="s" onclick="Start()">Start</button><br>
 <textarea id="txt" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you write `getElementsById`, it must be `getElementById`. Besides, you made things far more difficult. I simplified things a little bit. See this:

```js
var ti;

function Start() {

  var n = document.getElementById("addnumber").value;
  for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    var divNew = document.createElement("div");
    divNew.style.height = "50px";
    divNew.style.width = "50px";
    divNew.style.border = "5px solid green"
    divNew.style.display = "inline-block";
    divNew.innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * n) + 1);
    document.body.appendChild(divNew);

    divNew.onclick = function() {
      var me = this;
      this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("txt").value += me.innerHTML;
        document.body.removeChild(me);
        me = null;
      }, 3000);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="testjs.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>

<body>
  <p id="date"></p>
  <input type="number" name="Number:" id="addnumber">
  <button type="button" id="s" onclick="Start()">Start</button>
  <br>
  <textarea id="txt" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
  <br>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, now it works and seems to be easier than I thought it would be. Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
    ti = setInterval(del(i), 3000);
    function del(index){
      return function() {
        listDivs[index].style.backgroundColor="red";
        if ( l == 0) 
            clearInterval(ti);
        else {
            document.body.removeChild(listDivs[index]);
            document.getElementById("txt").value += listDivs[index].innerHTML;
        }
      };
    }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: `getElementsById` must be `getElementById`.

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

- Use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` as you create a callback function for each element anyway, so no need to do a count down, etc...
- Bind the clicked element to the callback function, because the index number cannot be relied on: as elements disappear, the index numbers also change.
- Convert strings to numbers before adding up, otherwise you will be concatenating instead of adding

Here is the code with those things corrected, with comments to indicate where:

```js
var ti;
function Start()
{
 
 var n=document.getElementById("addnumber").value;
 for(i=1; i<=10; i++)
 {
  var divNew = document.createElement("div");
  divNew.style.height = "50px";
  divNew.style.width = "50px";
  divNew.style.border = "5px solid green"
  divNew.style.display = "inline-block";
  divNew.textContent = Math.floor((Math.random()*n)+1);
  document.body.appendChild(divNew);
 }
    var listDivs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    var l = document.getElementsByTagName("div").length;
    console.log(l);
    for(let i=0; i<l; i++)
    {
        listDivs[i].onclick = function(){ 
            this.style.backgroundColor = "red"; // move out of callback
            setTimeout(function (){ // don't use setInterval: every element gets 
                                    // its own callback
                document.body.removeChild(this);
                document.getElementById("txt").value = // coerce strings to numbers
                        +document.getElementById("txt").value + +this.textContent; 
            }.bind(this), 1000);  // bind the element, because index will change
        };
    }
}
```

```html
<p id="date"></p>
 <input type="number" name="Number:" id="addnumber" value=20>
 <button type="button" id="s" onclick="Start()">Start</button><br>
 <textarea id="txt" rows="2" cols="50"></textarea><br>
```

I also replaced `innerHTML` by `textContent`, as the first is intended to insert HTML. Plain text should be not be set via `innerHTML` as in some situations it could have undesired side effects.